# how to play the cushion shot in snooker

Tags: snooker

In snooker, it is more difficult to pot the ball while your cue ball is placed with cushion.
I am playing snooker for nearly 4 years but till now I can't play this shot very well.
Can anyone tell me some (related) tricks and practice to improve this shot?